# How to undo the "Choose sources" operation for those compiled files in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, backend

When I encounter that my code is calling a method which is developed by other teams and is referenced using gradle build script, I couldn't see the source code by clicking into the moethod implementation. One way to debug this method is to click the "Choose sources" action in the top right corner reminded by Intellij IDEA.

How can I undo this "Choose sources" action?

Comment: "revoke" ? I suspect you're not a native English speaker; in this context the word does not make sense to me. And I can't guess what you did intend.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks for reminding. I've modified my description.

Comment: Please check this discussion: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206822215-what-does-Choose-Sources-do-and-how-can-I-undo-what-it-does-